# how to iterate through a list and get values based on the value of the previous index in python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Basically, I have a list, and I am iterating through every odd numbered index in the list.  What I want to do, is based on the value of each odd numbered index, to then update a variable with the value in the even numbered index directly after said odd numbered index.

So if `lst[1]` contains the value `p`, then I want the value of `x` to be the value at `lst[2]: x = lst[2]`.

If `lst[3]` contains the value `m` then I want y to be the value at `lst[4]: y = lst[4]`

The length of the list is never set in stone, since it grabs it from a file.

I am currently iterating through the list using this code:

```
for item in lst:
    if lst[range(1, len(lst), 2] == "p"
        x = ??
```

EDIT:  I suppose to be more specific, I have created a class, and now am creating a function that will take information from a file, and use it to fill in the methods in my class.  To do so I am reading in the file using `readlines` and then going through that list created by `readlines` and updating the methods in my class depending on what is in the file.  Every odd line in the file is an indicator of which method I need to update with the line that comes directly after.

So:

```
if lst[1] == "p":
   s.methodOne(lst[2])
if lst[1] == "m":
    s.methodTwo(lst[2])
```

I'm just not sure how to grab what is in the even indexes after my odd ones.

My code is probably not very neat, but here is what I have so far:

```
def processScores(fname):
    infile = open(fname, 'r')
    lineinfo = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()
    lstinfo = []
    for item in lineinfo:
        lst = item.split(",")
        s = Score()
        s.initialize(lst[0])
        if lst[range(1, len(lst -1), 2] == "o" or "O":
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for idx in xrange(1, len(lst), 2):
    if lst[idx] == 'p':
        ...
    if lst[idx] == 'm':
        ...
```

Note that the first element of `lst` is `lst[0]`, so you are skipping it altogether here

Answer (score 0):

I like itertools:

```
from itertools import izip

def grouper(n, iterable):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip(*args)

line = 'hello, my name is really not pete.'
#              ^^                    ^^

for a, b in grouper(2, line[1:]):
    if a == 'm':
        print b
    elif a == 'p':
        print b
```

Result:

```
$ python oddeven.py
y
e
```